# What are the advantages/disadvantages of the Tomcat request handling instance?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

What are the advantages/disadvantages with regards to the fact that Tomcat only creates one instance of a Servlet class to handle all requests for a JSP/servlet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not Tomcat-specific, it's just conform the [Sun Java Servlet API specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index2.html). You can however go around this by letting the servlet implement the **deprecated** [`SingleThreadModel`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) interface.

Using a single instance applicationwide has the huge benfit that there's no means of overhead of creating a new instance on every request in busy environments. And the disadvantages? No one comes to mind. It makes perfectly sense.

Comment: What about an "extremely heavy" load on the server? Would it be better to have several instances if one is getting bogged down with too many requests?

Comment: That's no problem. Java is multithreaded. The same instance can be used simultaneously by multiple threads.

Comment: ...as long as you write threadsafe code yourself ;) I.e. do not assign request/session scoped data as instance variables. Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183974/difference-each-instance-of-servlet-and-each-thread-of-servlet-in-servlets/2184147#2184147