# JSF files inside WEB-INF directory, how do I access them?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsf-2, web-inf

I want to put my JSF 2.0 xhtml files under WEB-INF\jsf. How do I access them then? I know that anything inside WEB-INF isn't exposed to the outside, so I need a controller to redirect me to the corresponding JSP, right? (This is also the model 2 pattern iirc).

Can I achieve this with a parameter inside web.xml/faces-config.xml? I think the FacesServlet is the controller of my webapp so it should serve this purpose?

And another question for understanding the Model 2 Pattern. Does every action have to go first to a servlet which then handles the next possible step? So a simple `<a href="anotherPage.html" />` is forbidden in this pattern since it doesn't go to the controlling servlet?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> *I want to put my JSF 2.0 xhtml files under WEB-INF\jsf. How do I access them then?*

You cannot. Files in `/WEB-INF` folder are not directly accessible.

There are two options to workaround the problem of JSF source files being public accessible.

1. Map the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` instead of `*.jsf`.
2. Or, restrict direct access on `*.xhtml` by a `<security-constraint>` in `web.xml`.

   ```xml
   <security-constraint>
       <display-name>Restrict direct access to XHTML files</display-name>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>XHTML files</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint />
   </security-constraint>
   ```

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)
- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)

---

> *And another question for understanding the Model 2 Pattern. Does every action have to go first to a servlet which then handles the next possible step?*

The `FacesServlet` already does that. It's the controller. With JSF you already end up with a simple javabean as model and JSP/Facelets file as view. The `FacesServlet` as being the controller has already taken all the nasty work of request parameter gathering, validation, conversion, model updating and navigation from your hands.

#### See also:

- [What components are MVC in JSF MVC framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104094/what-components-are-mvc-in-jsf-mvc-framework)
- [JSF Controller, Service and DAO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao)

---

> *So a simple `<a href="anotherPage.html" />` is forbidden in this pattern since it doesn't go to the controlling servlet?*

No, it's perfectly fine. The controller will kick in whenever needed. If the resource doesn't need a controller (i.e. static resource), then you also don't need to let it pass through some controller.

---

In the future, please ask multiple questions in separate Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already mapped only *.xhtml files (option 1). 

I've read that in some frameworks (Struts, Spring Webflow,..) it's possible/the preferred way to put the jsp files (=dynamic content) under WEB-INF and the controller accesses them there and displays them to the user. I just wanted to ask if the same is possible with JSF. 
But if I see it correctly no one can view the source of the xhtml files through the browswer since they are always rendered through the controller, right?

Answer (score 1):

To access `xhtml` pages inside `WEB-INF/jsf` folder you may do next:

1. Move `xhtml` pages folder from `webapp root` to `WEB-INF`
2. Introduce "**Dispatcher View**" pattern to the project
3. Map "**Front Controller**" servlet to `url` based to pages from application
4. Map **Faces Servlet** to "`.xhtml`"
5. Inside "**Dispatcher**" forward request to page from "`WEB-INF/jsf/<name>.xhtml`"
6. Override `jsf ViewHandler getActionUrl` to exclude "`WEB-INF`" from generated `action` `url` (of `form, link, button`)

For example, `xhtml` pages are in webapp root folder "`jsf`". All `url` between pages are like `jsf/<pageName>.xhtml`. So we do next:

1. move `<webapp root>/jsf` to `<webapp root>/WEB-INF/jsf`
2. create **FrontController** servlet:

``

```
public class FrontController extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            process(req, resp);
        }

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
            process(req, resp);
        }    

        private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
             Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.getInstance();
             dispatcher.dispatch(request, response);
        }
}
```

3. map Front Controller servlet in `web.xml` to `url` based for pages:

> ```
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>Front Controller</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>controllers.FrontController</servlet-class>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>Front Controller</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/jsf/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

4. map **Faces Servlet** in `web.xml` to `.xhtml`

> ```
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

5. create **Dispatcher** which forwards `request` to correct `xhtml` page:

``

```
public class Dispatcher {

    public void dispatch(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String pageBase = "/WEB-INF/jsf/";
        String pagePath = null;
        String errorPage = "/WEB-INF/jsf/error.xthml";

        //here could be complicated logic to analyze if the page should be visible for security reasons, authorisation etc, business logic            
       //requested page could be taken from parsing requested URI
        //pageName = findPageNameFromURI(request.getRequestURI());

        pagePath = pageBase + pageName;

        //if page should not be visible
        pagePath = errorPage;            

        //forward to page inside WEB-INF/jsf
        request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(pagePath).
                                   forward(request, response);        
    }   

}
```

So if url for page was `/myapp/jsf/home.xhtml` then **Dispatcher** will forward it to `myapp/WEB-INF/jsf/home.xhtml`. And Faces Servlet will handle "`.xhtml`" request. But if on a page are used `jsf` components like `h:form, h:link, h:button` etc which generate `action` or `url` then the `url` will be really including "`/WEB-INF`". So to exclude it we need next step.

6. Exclude "`/WEB-INF`" from `jsf` generated `url` (for jsf form, link, button).
   For that:

   6.1 create subclass of `jsf ViewHandler` and override `getActionUrl`:

``

```
public class HiddenPageViewHandler extends ViewHandlerWrapper {

    private static final String WEB_INF = "/WEB-INF";

    private ViewHandler parent;

    public HiddenPageViewHandler(ViewHandler parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public String getActionURL(FacesContext context, String viewId) {
        String actionUrl = super.getActionURL(context, viewId);

        if (actionUrl != null && actionUrl.contains(WEB_INF)) {
            actionUrl = actionUrl.replace(WEB_INF, "");
        }        

        return actionUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHandler getWrapped() {
        return parent;
    }

}
```

6.2 configure `jsf` to use the specified `ViewHandler`. In `faces-config.xml` add next:

> ```
>    <application>
>     ...
>         <view-handler>
>             controllers.HiddenPageViewHandler
>         </view-handler>
>    </application>
> ```

Comment: Bad advice. This introduces a security hole: exposing all WEB-INF content directly into public.

Comment: it was for simplicity in dispatcher just to add WEB-INF before requested url.    For sure dispatcher maybe done as complicated as required. It is just an idea how to implement it.

Comment: edited the Dispatcher sample to forward only to page from WEB-INF/jsf with additional logic of page finding including security check or forwarding to error page

Comment: Still a rather clumsy solution to the concrete problem of hiding JSF source code files of public pages in case non-XHTML mapping was used. The current top answer shows how so solve it in much simpler ways.

Comment: sure, above answers give easier ways. But my solution is just to show benefits of usage Dispatcher View with JSF. And one benefit of it is a possibility to access jsf files from WEB-INF. Also Dispatcher View pattern allows to use logical mapping strategy for JSF page. In Dispatcher it is possible to analyze url like /myapp/jsf/home and forward it to /WEB-INF/jsf/home.xhtml (for Faces Servlet). In ViewHandler is possible to remove .xhtml extension from jsf generated url: if (actionUrl != null && actionUrl.contains(".xhtml")) {
            actionUrl = actionUrl.replace(".xhtml", "");
        }