# Production build JHipster with Joinfaces. Howto specify where to look for xhtml files

Tags: spring, maven, jsf, jhipster

I have just started to integrate JoinFaces into JHipster, which was really easy.

Following the example of JoinFaces, I put xhtml files to *src/resources/META-INF/resources*

Normal builds like *mvn -Pdev spring-boot:run* run without any problems.

I struggle at just one last piece in the puzzle, the production build. 
As stated above, xhtml files are stored in *src/resources/META-INF/resources*. After a production build *mvn -Pprod package*, they are located inside the war at */WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources/*.

Running the application results in *Status: Not Found (Not Found)
Message: Not Found* at *http://localhost:8080/index.jsf*

How am I fixing this? I really have no idea where the jhipster spring-boot app expects them to be. Then I could adjust the pom accordingly (thinking maven-resource plugin)

Comment: Please improve your title... And in 99% of the cases, the webapp is looking for the xhtml files in the wrong place. This is not the default place? Where do you normally put them? What is the config then? Did the config change now

Comment: I should improve my question so that it becomes more clear that yes, they are in the wrong place after doing a production build. I should point out that is clear that they are, as in 99,99% of the cases. I wonder if I should also improve my question so it becomes more clear that I search for a solution of this problem. The best place to start off would be the pom.xml, which is a 955 line long beast. Which is why I seek help.

Comment: Why not the other way around? Put them in the location where JSF can find them? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512234/jsf-files-inside-web-inf-directory-how-do-i-access-them

Comment: Non-Production builds work fine, I have to adjust the pom anyway, particularly for the production build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why not the other way around? Put them in the location where JSF can
>   find them?

Good idea. So playing around with it a bit more, I figured out that jhipster expects html files to be in **target/www/** when running into the *package* phase of Maven. I use the maven-resources-plugin for that.

The following adjustments to the pom.xml have been made:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/www/</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/</directory>
                                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have also excluded the **src/main/resources/** from sonar

```
<sonar.exclusions>src/main/webapp/content/**/*.*, src/main/webapp/bower_components/**/*.*,src/main/resources/META-INF/**/*.*,
        src/main/webapp/i18n/*.js, target/www/**/*.*
</sonar.exclusions>
```