# Blank page in jsf page

Tags: java, templates, jsf, primefaces

I have a blank page when i try to open my page http://localhost:8084/Gpsi-worked/admin.xhtml but when i try this http://localhost:8084/Gpsi-worked/faces/admin.xhtml that work where is the problem, im using template in my project.

Answer (score 9):

That's because the `FacesServlet` is mapped on an URL pattern of `/faces/*` instead of `*.xhtml`. The `FacesServlet` is the one responsible for doing all the JSF works. All requests to JSF pages have to invoke the `FacesServlet`. It will then parse the Facelets and JSF tags in the XML template and generate HTML code. Rightclick the blank page in your webbrowser and choose *View Source*. You'll see that all JSF tags are left unparsed. The webbrowser doesn't understand JSF tags, it only understands HTML.

In order to get rid of the `/faces/*` path, you need to change the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml` from

```xml
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
```

to

```xml
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

This has the only (minor) caveat that you cannot serve plain `.xhtml` files anymore without invoking the `FacesServlet`, but those files should actually be served as `.html` anyway ;)

#### See also:

- [Sometimes I see JSF URL is *.jsf, sometimes *.xhtml and sometimes /faces/*. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/sometimes-i-see-jsf-url-is-jsf-sometimes-xhtml-and-sometimes-faces-why)

Answer (score 0):

In `web.xml` you will specify a servlet mapping and it will be looking for a URL path with `/faces/*` (or perhaps `.faces` too) in order to send requests to the `FacesServlet`. Change the mapping to something more suitable, if you don't want the `/faces` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a blank page? Because you should have got an error, maybe if you look at the source of the blank page you might see your JSF page unprocessed ?