# Web application on cloud returns blank page

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

Java web project works on tomcat nicely. So I deployed it on appengine. But web site shows blank page.

I'm using maven3.5, Java8, JSF and primefaces.
When I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6237230/6934695) web.xml,
project.appspot.com/ returns this;

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
>   complete your request.  Please try again in 30 seconds.

And here is stacktrace:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory
>   javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.
>
> ```
>     at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory (FactoryFinderInstance.java:555)
>     at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory (FactoryFinder.java:283)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.init (FacesServlet.java:358)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet (ServletHolder.java:643)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize (ServletHolder.java:422)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize (ServletHandler.java:892)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext
> ```
>
> (ServletContextHandler.java:349)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1406)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1368)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:778)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:262)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:522)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler
>   (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:244)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler
>   (AppVersionHandlerMap.java:182)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest
>   (JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:97)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchServletRequest
>   (JavaRuntime.java:680)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.dispatchRequest
>   (JavaRuntime.java:642)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run
>   (JavaRuntime.java:612)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$NullSandboxRequestRunnable.run
>   (JavaRuntime.java:806)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run (ThreadGroupPool.java:274)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)

project.appspot.com/index.xhtml returns blank page.

appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>My Project</application><!-- unused for Cloud SDK based tooling -->
    <version>alpha-001</version><!-- unused for Cloud SDK based tooling -->
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <resource-files>
        <include path="/data.txt" />
    </resource-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>



  <!-- Welcome page -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- JSF mapping -->
  <servlet>
    <display-name>forbsyam</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>




  <!-- Map these files with JSF -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index2.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index3.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.forbs</groupId>
  <artifactId>forbsyam</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>forbsyam Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.59</version>
      </plugin>


    </plugins>

      <finalName>forbsyam</finalName>

  </build>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.15</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.tools/appengine-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
      <version>8.5.24</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
      <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
      <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Which part I'm missing?

EDIT: With this web.xml appspot.com/ does not show error, just blank page.

EDIT2: I checked project.appspot.com/ 's source. It show my index.xhtml without render.