# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config

Tags: jsf, jstl, classnotfoundexception

When I am run my application after entering the URL, this exception is coming.I am using Eclipse and Tomcat7.0.35. I also added Jstl.jar and jstl1.2.jar

My code is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.jsp.JspViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(JspViewDeclarationLanguage.java:91)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:241)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you provide the list of the libraries in you classpath? seems you are missing the `jstl.jar` in your classpath

Comment: I added jsf-myfaces,jstl,primefaces libraries in both classpath and buildpath

Comment: @Sagar You need to ensure that the jars are in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. See my answer.

Comment: find the bug-- For some reason jstl jars are removing every time from my eclipse deployment path

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Download the following jars and add it to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory:

- [jsp-api-2.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.jar)
- [jstl-1.2.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar)

Comment: In my case, I only needed to add jstl-1.2.jar.

Comment: Added and worked for me.

Comment: It works!! You can find the jar here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

Answer (score 74):

The error is telling you it cannot find the class because it is not available in your application.

If you are using *Maven*, make sure you have the dependency for `jstl` artifact:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using it, just make sure you include the JAR in your classpath. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292916/1300817) for download links.

Comment: @RaulGogo-I am not using Maven

Comment: The last paragraph is for the case in which you don't have Maven. See the answer in the link provided.

Comment: For anyone else who might have the same issue I did, my mistake was using `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl` as the groupId instead of `javax.servlet`

Answer (score 9):

By default, Tomcat container doesn’t contain any jstl library. To fix it, declares jstl.jar in your Maven pom.xml file if you are working in Maven project or add it to your application's classpath

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the jstl libraries are missing from your classpath/not accessible by tomcat.

You need to add at least the following jar files in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory:

- jsf-impl.jar
- jsf-api.jar
- jstl.jar

Comment: ... and do **not** fiddle with project's *Build Path* setting. Untouch it and undo if necessary any changes you made there. Just dropping the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` is sufficient. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info Note that JSTL 1.2 is only one JAR file, not two. So if you have `jstl.jar` and `jstl-1.2.jar`, you should remove the first one.

Comment: @BalusC Good point. Thanks BalusC.

Answer (score 3):

Add `jstl` jar to your application classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick comment: sometimes Maven does not copy the jstl-.jar to the WEB-INF folder even if the pom.xml has the entry for it.

I had to manually copy the JSTL jar to /WEB-INF/lib on the file system. That resolved the problem. The issue may be related to Maven war packaging plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Add [JSTL library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2) as dependency to your project (`javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config` is a part of this package).
For example, if you were using [Gradle](http://gradle.org/), you could write in a build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Go to Project Properties -> Deployment Assemplbly and add jstl jar