# NoClassDefFoundError running JSF in Spring-boot

Tags: jsf, spring-boot

I'm tring to get work Spring-boot with primfaces. I followed this examle https://github.com/Zergleb/Spring-Boot-JSF-Example . I tried moved it from gradle to maven becasue other part of project use maven, but I allways get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
```

I was searching and I found this solution [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113628/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-core-config) but it didn't worked for me.

This is my dependencies list from pom file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-02</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8-02</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I also tried download needed libraries and put them into WEB-INF/lib but didn't work.I'm using Intelij 14.

Answer (score 3):

this combination of dependencies helped me out to get Spring Boot up and running with JSF.

These libraries provide to the embedded Tomcat the necessary classes to handle the JSF servlet requests an EL expressions correctly.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am able to run it using mvn springboot:run at the command line. In Intellij Idea we can run it as a Maven project and giving "spring-boot:run" at the command line parameter field. **Runs perfectly fine for Tomcat 7, Spring Boot 1.2.3 , JSF Mojarra 2.2.11 , PrimeFaces 6.1** . The following needed to be added to the pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and change the provided scope(doesn't send jar file to tomcat) to compile scope(add spring-boot-starter-tomcat.jar to WEB-INF\lib) in POM.xml.
after this change tomcat can start my application without any exceptions.
I hope, It can help others to solve such exception.