# ERROR 11616 --- [ main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new in Spring. And I am getting this error from long time and I didn't understand what to do. I try to fix it by adding dependencies. But It's not working and giving same error again and again. Please help me. Here is my log.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=60402:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\bin" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\SpringBootTutorials\WebApp\target\classes;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.0\spring-boot-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.0\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.7\logback-classic-1.2.7.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.7\logback-core-1.2.7.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.29\snakeyaml-1.29.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.0\jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.0\jackson-annotations-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.0\jackson-core-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.0\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.0\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.6.0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.13\spring-web-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.13\spring-beans-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.13\spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.13\spring-aop-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.13\spring-context-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.13\spring-expression-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\10.0.13\tomcat-jasper-10.0.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-servlet-api\10.0.13\tomcat-servlet-api-10.0.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\10.0.13\tomcat-juli-10.0.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jsp-api\9.0.55\tomcat-jsp-api-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-el-api\10.0.13\tomcat-el-api-10.0.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\ecj\3.26.0\ecj-3.26.0.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper-el\10.0.13\tomcat-jasper-el-10.0.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-api\10.0.13\tomcat-api-10.0.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-util-scan\10.0.13\tomcat-util-scan-10.0.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-util\10.0.13\tomcat-util-10.0.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\jakarta\servlet\jsp\jakarta.servlet.jsp-api\2.3.4\jakarta.servlet.jsp-api-2.3.4.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.13\spring-core-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\surya\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.13\spring-jcl-5.3.13.jar com.suryakant.webapp.WebAppApplication
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.0)

2021-11-28 19:28:31.028  INFO 11616 --- [           main] com.suryakant.webapp.WebAppApplication   : Starting WebAppApplication using Java 17.0.1 on Suryakant-PC with PID 11616 (D:\SpringBootTutorials\WebApp\target\classes started by surya in D:\SpringBootTutorials\WebApp)
2021-11-28 19:28:31.028  INFO 11616 --- [           main] com.suryakant.webapp.WebAppApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-11-28 19:28:32.525  WARN 11616 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
2021-11-28 19:28:32.541  INFO 11616 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-11-28 19:28:32.587 ERROR 11616 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at com.suryakant.webapp.WebAppApplication.main(WebAppApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.<clinit>(JasperInitializer.java:52) ~[tomcat-jasper-10.0.13.jar:10.0.13]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.addJasperInitializer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.prepareContext(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:248) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:205) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.jsp.JspFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Here is my pom.xml file:**

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.6.0
 

com.suryakant
WebApp
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
WebApp
WebApp

<java.version>17</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <version>10.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp/jakarta.servlet.jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <version>10.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

and

Try adding the following dependencies to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Same error is coming after adding this dependencies also.

Comment: @SuryakantThakur did you remove `jakarta.servlet.jsp-api`?

Comment: Yes.. I removed it...

Comment: @SuryakantThakur please see the edited answer now

Comment: It's working fine now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When NoClassDefFoundError occurs, it is most often caused by the versions of the dependent libraries do not match.
Please check the link

[NoClassDefFoundError running JSF in Spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725880/noclassdeffounderror-running-jsf-in-spring-boot)