# Servlet mapping jsf

Tags: jsf

I'm asking myself which way is the best for servlet mapping in jsf? And Why?

Especially I'm wondering always about the different suffix of the facelet resources and the suffix of the url-pattern of the servlet-mapping. My servlet mapping is always coherent to the suffix of my resources.

For Example if I'm using xhtml as facelets my servlet mapping does it also:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But I see examples where the resources are xhtml files and the servlet mapping is on jsf?

For Example:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

So which way is the best way?

And also I'm wondering why the second way working at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now you won't need an answer on which servlet mapping to use, I think. You would probably be better of with some reading first.
I have taken the liberty to find two related questions which might open your eyes a little considering JSF and the file extension.

- [What is the difference between creating JSF pages with .jsp or .xhtml or .jsf extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914660/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-xhtml-or-jsp-or-jsf-for-jsf-pages)
- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)