# How to change index.html in every folder to / when we access it on browser

Tags: jsf, web

I've some unique problem, but I think this is not problem, I just want to optimize the url that my website have.

so I want to change all

```
index.html
```

on every folder as example

```
culture
```

folder, so normally if we want access

```
index.html
```

in culture folder we can just type

```
culture/index.html
```

right? but i want to access by just type

```
culture/
```

Is it possible to do that? If so, how we produce? I'm using `jsf 2` as programming language.

Comment: Take a look at prettyfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand your problem, but this can be done by [configuring welcome files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/configurejsp.html#wp157851) in the `web.xml` file:

> Web Application developers can define an ordered list of partial URIs
>   called welcome files in the Web application deployment descriptor. The
>   purpose of this mechanism is **to allow the deployer to specify an
>   ordered list of partial URIs for the container to use for appending to
>   URIs when there is a request for a URI that corresponds to a directory
>   entry in the WAR not mapped to a Web component.** This feature can make
>   your site easier to use, because the user can type a URL without
>   giving a specific filename.
>
> Note: Welcome files can be JSPs, static pages, or servlets.

Just:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

---

I've tested this on WildFly 11 and it works, my project structure is:

```
+ WebContent
   - index.xhtml
   + folder_a
        - index.xhtml
   + folder_b
        - index.html
   + folder_c
        - other_name.xhtml
        - some_name.html
```

When I enter:

- `http://localhost:8080/myproject/` I get a content from `WebContent/index.xhtml`
- `http://localhost:8080/myproject/folder_a` I get a content from `WebContent/folder_a/index.xhtml`
- `http://localhost:8080/myproject/folder_b` I get a content from `WebContent/folder_b/index.html`

---

> Does the .xhtml file contain JSF content? is it parsed? I always
>   thought defining a jsf/facelets file as a welcome file did not work
>   and you needed http redirects via 'meta-inf'

`.jsf' is that an extension I am using in my`web.xml` file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please read answers for the below question to learn what it is:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)
- [What is the difference between creating JSF pages with .jsp or .xhtml or .jsf extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914660/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-jsf-pages-with-jsp-or-xhtml-or-jsf-ex)

Comment: Does the  .xhtml file contain JSF content? is it parsed? I always thought defining a jsf/facelets file as a welcome file did not work and you needed http redirects via 'meta-inf' (see the last note in your quote)

Comment: I've updated the answer with an explanation hat is `jsf`

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2.0 does not have support for extensionless URL by default. This is a long waited feature for the community, but finally we got this with JSF 2.3 (released early 2017). If you care able to update your application to JSF 2.3, or maybe want some more information, please check it out [here](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#1260).

A brief example of how you can make the default JSF approach for extensionless URLs:

In the web.xml file, include each desired mapping using a  tag inside the  tag:

```
  <url-pattern>/page1</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/page2</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/path/page1</url-pattern>
```

These patterns will redirect the user to the following paths respectively:

> - www.domain.com/page1 -> www.domain.com/page1.xhtml
> - www.domain.com/page2 -> www.domain.com/page2.xhtml
> - www.domain.com/path/page1 -> www.domain.com/path/page1.xhtml

***Note that the above examples are not providing a way to redirect to the index.xhtml page, they are just a example of how the new JSF 2.3 mapping work.***

However, if you can't update your project right now, I suggest you to follow @Kukeltje advice and take a look on the [PrettyFaces](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) library.

PrettyFaces is focused on provide a simple way to create URL mappings for older JSF versions. Heres a example of how it works:

In the pretty-config.xml file, include your desired mappings using a  tag:

```
<url-mapping id="view-page">
    <pattern value="/page" />
    <view-id value="/page/index.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
<url-mapping id="view-page-edit">
    <pattern value="/page/#{id}" />
    <view-id value="/page/edit.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

These patterns would work like the following examples:

> - www.domain.com/page -> www.domain.com/page/index.xhtml
> - www.domain.com/page/2 -> www.domain.com/page/edit.xhtml?id=2

Both are good alternatives, PrettyFaces looks more powerful right now, since they are support this kind of solution for more time, but the JSF 2.3 should also do the trick.