# Eclipse shows invalid character or invalid text string or tag not closed properly

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, jsp-tags

Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) reports error at this line of code:

```
<select id="<%=province.id%>" data-placeholder=" " <%=province.multiple%> class="chzn-select" style="margin: 1px auto;width:260px;">
</select>
```

Reported errors are:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Start tag (<select>) not closed properly, expected '>'.
- Invalid character used in text string (<%=province.multiple%> class="chzn-select" style="margin: 1px auto;width:260px;">).
- Invalid text string (<%=province.multiple%> class="chzn-select" style="margin: 1px auto;width:260px;">).
```

When I remove `<%=province.multiple%>` from the line, Eclipse stops reporting those errors, but as far as I know, this is valid code. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Should this

`<select id="<%=province.id%>" data-placeholder=" " <%=province.multiple%> class="chzn-select" style="margin: 1px auto;width:260px;">`

be (updated)

`<select id="<%=province.id%>" data-placeholder=" " multiple="<%=province.multiple%>" class="chzn-select" style="margin: 1px auto;width:260px;">`

Not necessary related in this case but found this also (see details [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_select_multiple.asp)):

> In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the multiple
>   attribute must be defined as input multiple="multiple"

Then the file suffix might also make Eclipse more critical: if it is `.xhtml`
 contents propably must be `.xhtml`.

One good - maybe not directly related - question: [What is the difference between creating JSF pages with .jsp or .xhtml or .jsf extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914660/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-jsf-pages-with-jsp-or-xhtml-or-jsf-ex)

Comment: No, `<%=province.multiple%>` echoes `multiple` attribute name or empty string to enable or disable selecting multiple values: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Ok, but guess that eclipse complains because it encounters starting  `<` before select tag is closed, maybe an editor bug. Or maybe accidentally inserted hidden char.