# How to get context path in JSF

Tags: jsp, jsf, servlets

I'm transforming some JSP pages to JSF ones and this is my problem:

In JSP i have this line:

```
<form name="form" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/LoginServlet" method="post">
```

As you can see `/LoginServlet` is my Servlet where all login functions are done. So how I can implement that in JSF page?

Comment: Don't post to a servlet but use a bean and action. Take a step back and learn JSF basics first. Start at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: @JasperdeVries: same person as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266720/is-it-good-to-use-jsf-and-jsp-in-same-time