# Glassfish with JSF and Icefaces

Tags: jsf, tags, glassfish, render, icefaces

I'm migrating a jboss JSF/IceFaces application to Glassfish 3.1.2.2. I've created the datasources, deployed the application, but unexpectedly the browser shows me the JSF code, it just doenst render the JSF. If I've followed the "standard" for JSF and it works in Weblogic and jboss, what can be wrong in the Glassfish?

thanks for your help,
José Cruz

Answer (score 0):

That will happen if the `FacesServlet` isn't been invoked. You need to make sure that the request URL (as you see in browser's address bar) matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as you've definied in webapp's `web.xml`.

So if you've set the URL pattern to for example `*.jsf`, then you need to make sure that the request URL is like http://example.com/context/page.jsf and thus not like http://example.com/context/page.xhtml.

Alternatively, you could also change the URL pattern to `*.xhtml`, so that you never need to worry about virtual URLs.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/3008504#3008504)

Comment: The application works great in weblogic and jboss 7. So the configuration somehow its correct. I'm trying to figure out if there are any issues that I must be aware when migrating to glassfish, because the JSF isnt rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, which by the way its not a great solution, was creating an empty application starting from ground zero, creating an icefaces page, making sure that it was working. Then, we migrated the rest of the project to inside of this one.
I dont like this solution, but it worked. 
It's not the first time while migrating web apps, JPA and other Java techs between applications servers compatibility(or just strange) issues like this arrive from nowhere. 
Hope this help anyone in the future.

Anyway, thanks for the comments.

José Cruz