# Requests not being routed to JSF Servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, jsf-2, url-pattern

I have a JSF webapp which is exhibiting the following behaviour:
`http://localhost/myapp/` returns the raw contents of index.xhtml
`http://localhost/myapp/web/` returns a blank page
`http://localhost/myapp/web/index.xhtml` returns the error `/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource`

The directory structure of the webapp is shown below:

[image]

The web.xml file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
      <display-name>myapp</display-name>
       <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
      </context-param>
       <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
      </session-config>

    <!--   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
     -->  
    </web-app>
```

I have a breakpoint in the first line of the method `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service`

```
public void service(ServletRequest req,
                    ServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    requestStart(request.getRequestURI()); // V3 Probe hook
```

This breakpoint is never hit. Is anyone able to shed some light on what may be wrong here or some pointers on where I can start my investigations.

Comment: Did you tried to change `url-pattern` to `*.xhtml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF will trim off own URL pattern from the request URL before finding the resource. You need to put `/index.xhtml` file exactly there where JSF expects it as per the error message: in `/index.xhtml`. So, outside the `/web` folder. Note that you can just keep using `/web` in request URL.

An alternative is to just map the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml`. This way you don't need to worry about virtual URLs.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)

Comment: The problem with placing index.xhtml outside the /web directory whilst maintaining the /web/* URL mapping is that the request http://localhost/myapp/index.xhtml will return the raw index.xhtml file. In the original message I did not mention that I have a RestEasy servelet mapped to /rest/* and what I'm trying to do is to make sure that webpage requests are handled by the JSF FacesServlet and for the REST requests to be handled by the ResteasyServlet.

Comment: Then just use a mapping of `*.xhtml`?

Comment: Yes, I could do that however, what would happen to a request for `http://localhost/rest/some-method.xhtml`? I think this would be routed to FacesServlet too right?

Comment: Put the rest servlet in front of the faces servlet in web.xml. The first match wins.