# window.location.href doesn't render Facelets page, raw source code is returned

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

I have a problem with loading Facelets pages from Javascript. I'm working with Netbeans 7.2, Glassfish 3.1.2 and Java EE 6.

I made a simple test page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "index.xhtml";
    </script>
    <title>winq match!</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>WING MATCH!!</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton id="Next" value="weiter" action="index"/> 
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

The `index.xhtml` page that should be loaded with `window.location.href` is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="TestTestTestTestTest"/>
        msg <h:inputText id="ema" value="#{testBean.inputValue}" maxlength="1" />      
        <h:commandButton id="but" value="Submit" action="index"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

The page is loaded but not parsed and thus the `h:` tags are not interpreted by the browser. After searching the web on this it seems that I'm the only one with a problem like this. Maybe I´ve misunderstood some aspects of JSF. I hope to get some advise on this.

Comment: Please show your HTML output, not your JAVA server-side code.

Comment: @Diodeus that code is almost how the generated HTML will look, besides this is not Java server side code, it's JSF code.

Comment: Your problem must be in your web.xml file. Please add the configuration for the Faces Servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the request URL matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as definied in webapp's `web.xml`. It's namely the one responsible for performing all the JSF/Facelets works.

For example, if you've mapped it on `*.jsf`, then you should open the page on exactly that URL pattern so that the `FacesServlet` is properly invoked and will locate the `index.xhtml` file and do all the necessary stuff.

```
window.location.href = "index.jsf";
```

Alternatively, you can also change the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` to `*.xhtml`. This way you never need to worry about virtual URLs.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This leds me to the solution. In web.xml I declared: <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>. And I also tried         window.location.href = "/faces/index.xhtml" but this leads to the same problem as only "index.xhtml". My mistake was the leading slash. It has to be window.location.href = "faces/index.xhtml". Thx again to all, you´ve saved my day.

Comment: After changing `/faces/*` to `*.xhtml` I get: "/faces/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource" on pageload. Maybe some other parameters have to be also changed according to this (or it has to be /faces/*.xhtml, i will try this later).

Comment: Just remove `/faces` from URL in all places.