# Faces Servlet not parsing .xhtml pages in jsf 2. running on tomcat 7

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7

I am trying to create a JSF 2.0 application in eclipse with tomcat7. The project is running successfully but the jsf html and core components are not rendered in browser. I think Faces Servlet I have configured in web.xml.

Following is the web.xml file -

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>    
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>  

<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default)</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

I have my index.xhtml page outside WEB-INF. Its shown in browser but the jsf components are not see in browser. Can anyone please tell what is going wrong.

I have included following jars in WEB-INF/lib -
1. commons-annotations.jar
2. commons-beansutil.jar
3. commons-collection.jar
4. commons-digester.jar
5. commons-logging.jar
6. jsf-api.jar  (from mojra 2.0)
7. jsf-impl.jar (from mojra 2.0)
8. jstl.jar
9. standard.jar

Thanks

Comment: pls add contents of your index page. also hoe you are accessing the page. i hope the url is as per url mapping for jsf, containting /faces/ as above in conf.

Comment: Please, show us your page and the URL you use to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these .. These were specified to me for my own question once..

1. You don't need and even should not include the JSF jars. Those are already part of Java EE.
2. Secondly, you definitely don't need and absolutely should not use the separate Facelets jar in combination with JSF 2.x. Facelets is already part of JSF 2.x.
3. You also should not include the JSTL jar. That one too is provided by Java EE. If u have commons jars by Apache commons, then those are fine but they are NOT needed for JSF. Include them only if you want to use them directly in your application code.
4. Try to get latest JSF (mojara 2.x).

Also you can modify your web.xml like this and try:

```
 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>    
 </welcome-file-list> 


 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>    
 </servlet-mapping>
```

When I tried, I removed adding jsf jars separately. And it worked, displaying all the jsf tags. Also make sure you have all the required taglibs in your xhtml page, namely :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

See if this works.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I wasn't using the jars provided by Java EE. I used them and the JSF components started showing up in browser.

Comment: @sandeepk you mean , you deleted the jars which you had put earlier for jsf?

Comment: Yes, I had previously downloaded jars and used it with Tomcat. Then, I  created a sample JSF app in Glassfish (Netbeans). The issue was fixed after using those jars. I think it was happening because jars were wrong initially.

Comment: Answer items 1., 2. and 3. are to be ignored cause Tomcat 7 is *not* a JavaEE container and thus not equipped at all with JSF. Answer 4 is also to be given up because such a basic scenario must work with every release of JSF.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your servlet mapping shown in your original question to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>    
</servlet-mapping>
```

to make it work, i.e. to have your content (which is already happily served by Tomcat) rendered via JSF2.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why, explaining partially the *.jsf, *.xhtml, /faces/* mysteries.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and as this question is the first result on google queries about JSF not parsing xhtml files, here is what I have done to solve:

In my case I had a dependency on weld-servlet, version 2.2.1, when I removed it from classpath the JSF started rendering.

Hope this help!