# My IndexServlet runs in an infinite loop

Tags: servlets, infinite-loop

I'm trying to set up an environment to develop a Java EE app using a MariaDB database, PrimeFaces, Spring (with MVC) and Hibernate.
I've been trying to start it for a few days with no luck: each time I try to load my index.xhtml, Tomcat loops on a exception, as-in, the exception loops back indefinitely in the server log until I stop the server. However, the server starts fine when my index is a JSP...
Here's my pom.xml:

```
<groupId>mygroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the exception Tomcat is showing:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: L''exécution de la servlet a lancé une exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
net.myproject.servlet.IndexServlet.doGet(IndexServlet.java:18)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
net.myproject.servlet.IndexServlet.doGet(IndexServlet.java:18)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
net.myproject.servlet.IndexServlet.doGet(IndexServlet.java:18)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
net.myproject.servlet.IndexServlet.doGet(IndexServlet.java:18)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
net.myproject.servlet.IndexServlet.doGet(IndexServlet.java:18)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
net.myproject.servlet.IndexServlet.doGet(IndexServlet.java:18)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
```

[...and it goes on.]

My index is a simple hello world but here it is, just in case...

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form>
        <p:editor value="This is PrimeFace editor" />
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Finally, here is my IndexServlet:

```
package net.myproject.servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "Index", urlPatterns = {"/"})
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/").forward(req, resp);
}
}
```

Here's my AppConfig.java:

```
package net.myproject.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = {@ComponentScan("net.myproject.dao"),
    @ComponentScan("net.myproject.service")})
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("LOCAL_PERSISTENCE");
    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionJpaManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
}
```

I don't if it's my code that has a problem or if it's my IDE (IDEA IntelliJ) that's not properly configured.

I'd really love some help for this, cheers!

Comment: Does this help at all? [faces servlet not parsing xhtml pages in jsf 2 running on tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14806862/faces-servlet-not-parsing-xhtml-pages-in-jsf-2-running-on-tomcat-7)

Comment: @JGlass I am not using a web.xml configuration file, instead I use annotations and an AppConfig.java. I've added it to my original post.