# how to use jsf form in jboss 7.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I have this in my web.xml:

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login_page.xhtml</form-login-page>
        </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

login_page.xhtml has some jsf code that is not rendering when jboss redirect to him.

How can i use jsf instead html pages inside `<form-login-page>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSF works are done by the `FacesServlet`.

You need to make sure that the URL matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet`. Given your problem, it seems that you don't have it mapped on the simple URL pattern of `*.xhtml`, but on something else, like `*.jsf`, `*.faces` or `/faces/*`. You should then change the URL in such way that it matches exactly that URL pattern.

Imagine that it's `*.jsf`, then you need to change it as such:

```html
<form-login-page>/login_page.jsf</form-login-page>
```

However, easier is to just map the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml`. This way you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs.

```html
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/3008504#3008504)

Answer (score 0):

easy just use form-error-page tag:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/yourlogin.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/yourloginError.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

Comment: This isn't exactly OP's concrete problem.