# url goes wrong extension xhtml to jsp

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, tomcat7

I try to go to my page "index.xhtml", entering /index.xhtml in browser address bar but it caused 404 error that the index.jsp was not found. I dont have any idea why jsp is called.

My view:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
       <h:head>
           <title>This is a Test</title>    
       </h:head> 
       <h:body>
           <div>
               <H2>
                   <h:outputText value="test"/>
               </H2>
           </div>
       </h:body>
</html>
```

My web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Are you really using JSF2? The problem suggests that you're actually using JSF1. It'd be helpful if you elaborate which JARs exactly you placed in classpath, and where you downloaded them from, and which resources you used to learn JSF.

Comment: thanks so much it was realy JSF 1 jar. it was old project that i inculed. Therefore what will i have to this topic, delete or approve as answerd ?

Comment: I reposted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggests that you're *actually* not using JSF 2.x, but JSF 1.x. In JSF 1.x, the `FacesServlet` will by default use `.jsp` suffix to locate the view file based on the request URL. So, when `index.xhtml` is requested, it will look for the physical file `index.jsp`. In JSF 2.x the default suffix has changed to `.xhtml`, which means that when `index.xhtml` is requested, it will look for the physical file `index.xhtml`.

The `*.xhtml` in the `<url-pattern>` is merely the URL pattern on which the `FacesServlet` has to listen for on incoming HTTP requests.

In order to properly use JSF 2.x, you should get rid of all JSF 1.x libraries in the runtime classpath. This covers among others the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder. If you're unsure about the version because it's not mentioned in JAR's filename, extract it using a ZIP tool and look in `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Or just delete them all and re-download the right one from http://javaserverfaces.java.net.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/)

Comment: I have same issue even while I'm using JSF 2.x. The reason is I put my resource files at wrong location. When the Servlet can not find the resource file, it fall back to old JSF 1.x suffix pattern ( in this case *.jsf )