# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ViewTag.doStartTag

Tags: jsp, jsf, nullpointerexception, myfaces

I am using MyFaces 1.2 with WAS 7.0 and Myeclipse Blue 10.7. I am getting the following error. I have researched Internet pretty thoroughly but to no avail. Logs don't present much. MyEclipse does not have JSF trace debug utility like IBM RAD.

```
[8/8/13 10:41:19:447 EDT] 00000018 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[/sui_index.jsp]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.myfaces.taglib.core.ViewTag.doStartTag(ViewTag.java:75)
    at com.ibm._jsp._sui_5F_welcome._jspx_meth_f_view_0(_sui_5F_welcome.java:755)
    at com.ibm._jsp._sui_5F_welcome._jspService(_sui_5F_welcome.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1664)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:940)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:503)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is typical when you open a JSP page containing JSF components by a request URL which does not match the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet`. Basically, the JSF components in the JSP page are expecting to the `FacesContext` to be available by `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()`. However, it returned `null` which in turn ultimately caused this `NullPointerException`.

Note that the stack trace also doesn't give any hint that the `FacesServlet` is properly been called. The call went directly to the container's own JSP servlet, which is `HttpJspBase` in case of Websphere, instead of JSF's own `FacesServlet`.

In order to sovle this problem, just look in the `web.xml` on which URL pattern the `FacesServlet` is been mapped. In JSF 1.x, this is usually `*.jsf` or maybe `*.faces` or very maybe `/faces/*`. Once you figured that, just make sure that the request URL, as you see in browser's address bar, matches exactly that URL pattern. So, instead of for example

> http://example.com/context/sui_index.jsp

you should depending on the actual mapping be using either

> http://example.com/context/sui_index.jsf

or

> http://example.com/context/sui_index.faces

or

> http://example.com/context/faces/sui_index.jsp

Either way, this way the `FacesServlet` will be invoked and be able to properly prepare the `FacesContext` as expected by the JSF components in the JSP page.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/)