# Ajax not working JSF 2.2

Tags: java, ajax, tomcat, ajax4jsf, jsf-2.2

I'm using JSF 2.2 with TomCat 6. When I execute an ajax function the fields are not updated. I created a new project with just one controller and page even so, the ajax calls doesn't work.
It calls the method but doesn't update the page.

```xhtml
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich" xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j" xmlns:ajax="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="formTest">
        <h:outputLabel value="#{teste.teste}" id="testando" />
        <h:inputText value="#{teste.teste}" />
        <a4j:commandButton action="#{teste.agir}" render="formTest" execute="formTest" />

    </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Controller:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "teste")
@SessionScoped
public class Teste {

private String teste = "oi";

public void agir() {
teste = "666666";
System.out.println(getTeste());
}

public String getTeste() {
return teste;
}

public void setTeste(String teste) {
this.teste = teste;
}
}
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>Try</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>

      </welcome-file-list>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
     <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
       <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <listener>
       <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
     </listener>
    </web-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tomcat 6 is based in Servlet 2.5 spec, while JSF 2.2 requires Servlet 3.0.** Don't get puzzled by it, upgrade your Tomcat version to 7.x branch or downgrade the JSF implementation version to 2.1.x.

**See also:**

- [Apache Tomcat Version Details](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)
- [What's new in JSF 2.2?](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/)
- [JSF-Servlet compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194992/1199132)

Comment: Thanks man. It worked, I thought It was working with 2.2 and tomcat 6 because everything worked but Ajax. I have another question... when I execute the project I got 404 (localhost:8080/Try) I have to insert manually "index.jsf" to work. I downgrade to 2.1.x But this still happens. Any Idea?

Comment: Don't use `*.jsf` extensions. If you're actually at JSF 2, use facelets, with `*.xhtml`. Take care of changing your url-pattern to `*.xhtml` at web.xml.