# Primefaces doens't work when I call the xhtml archive

Tags: jsf, primefaces

As the title says.... The primefaces components that I'm using **don't work when I call .xhtml files**, only at startup, where no xhtml file is called

Here is the proof:

**Works (shows the primefaces datatable)**
[image]

**Doesn't works (the table is not there)**

[image]

Comment: what is the URL pattern you mentioned in `web.xml`?

Comment: <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
This url pattern was auto generated, i haven't touched the web.xml

Comment: Can you try to replace this with `*.xhtml` and run the application?

Comment: Are you the creator of primefaces????
IT ABSOLUTELY WORKED!
I was like crazy finding solution for this! Thanks!
Please put it as an answer so I can give you points

Comment: That's just basic Servlet API knowledge. You was just never invoking the `FacesServlet` (and hence it couldn't do its job of parsing JSF components so that they could generate the desired HTML output). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/3008504#3008504 To learn more about basic servlets, head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info