# Setting application URL on WAS server, where does /faces/ come from?

Tags: jsf, url

How is the URL set when an application is deployed on WAS server? Other than the context path I am setting, I am getting a `/faces/` in the URL. I have no clue from where this is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/faces/` is recognizable as JSF 1.0/1.1-style URL pattern where `FacesServlet` is often by default mapped on based on IDE-generated project configuratoin which weren't edited afterwards by the developer. You can see this in `web.xml` as something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet<servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Perhaps there's also a `<welcome-file>` on e.g. `faces/index.xhtml` or so.

In order to get rid of it, just replace it by `*.xhtml`.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet<servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This way you can open the JSF page by `http://example.com/context/page.xhtml` instead of `http://example.com/context/faces/page.xhtml` in order to trigger the `FacesServlet` (it's namely the one responsible for all the JSF works).

Or, when you're actually using legacy JSF 1.x and/or when you're actually using legacy JSP instead of its successor Facelets (XHTML), then you could use `*.jsf` instead.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet<servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This way you can open the JSF page by `http://example.com/context/page.jsf` instead of `http://example.com/context/faces/page.jsp`.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)