# How do i change the background of a JSF file

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

In html it is working perfectly , but I'm guessing it's not the same for a JSF file.
I'm trying to change the background color of body, to have a background color for my webPage
but it doesn't seem to work, Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255"/>
<title>Welcome</title>
</h:head>
<h:body style="background-color:blue;">

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you able to run this application properly and communicate with a managedbean?

Comment: I haven't yet tried, Does it matter?

Comment: Is this application running on some server? or did you just double click and open jsf file like its normally done for xhtml?

Comment: Oh.. yes it's running on tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the request URL as you see in the browser's address bar matches the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` as you've configured in your `web.xml`. Otherwise the JSF tags won't be parsed and won't produce the desired HTML output. You can confirm this by doing rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser. Instead of `<body>` the webbrowser would receive a `<h:body>` which it doesn't understand. You should not be seeing any JSF tags over there but instead its generated HTML output.

Imagine that it is `<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>`, then you should be opening the page as http://example.com/context/page.jsf instead of http://example.com/context/page.xhtml.

Otherwise, you'd better change the `<url-pattern>` to `*.xhtml` so that you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why/3008504#3008504)

Answer (score 2):

instead of using inline CSS style you can define your style for body tag

```
body { 
    background-color:blue; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty page that results in an empty body which is not displayed. Either put something in your body or change the style to:

```
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;background-color:blue;"
```

Comment: This is wrong and that even contradicts the fact that it worked fine in "plain HTML"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery code to change the colour of the body tag.(it works)

Actually your page is being added within another body tag... so by changing the body, you are not changing the real body's attributes.

JQuery helps you in almost everything.

`$( document ).ready(function() 
{
    $('body').css('background', 'blue');
});`

Comment: what if he is not using Jquery?

Comment: he/she has not mentioned it in the question.So, I went for the easiest and straight forward way...

Comment: Easiest way is to use CSS styles directly.

Comment: Holy ***, why does this non-answer suggesting a completely clumsy "solution" have 2 upvotes?

Comment: Because many people can take it as an answer atleast something that will solve the issue... and many can raise a question as you and two other member have done...