# JSF ServletException when file extension is ".jsf" but as ".xhtml"

Tags: jsf, facelets, servletexception

As soon as I try to open my index.xhtml via "http: //localhost:8080/beginner/faces/index.jsf" I'll get the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)

java.lang.NullPointerException
com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java:228)
com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:214)
com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)


note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final logs.
```

In eclipse I created a Maven Project via the "new Maven project wizard" and chose
Group Id: "org.jboss.spec.archetypes", Artifact Id "jboss-javaee6-webapp-blank-archetype" version: 7.13
I'm using JBoss 7.1.1.FINAL and tried JDK 6 and JDK7

the index.xthml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>First JSF</title>
    </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <h1>Hello there</h1>
        </h:body>
</html>
```

Im looking for hours for a reason, but cant find any solution, even though I did every step that this workshop-book told me to do.

Comment: It will be good to see what is in your web.xml? It might be related to the servlet and url-patterns you are using.

Answer (score 6):

Is it really a XHTML (Facelets) file?

Look closer at the classname in the following line of the stack trace to learn who's handling the view:

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:214)
```

Hey, it's being treated as a JSP file! Something's definitely not entirely right here. One would expect a `FaceletViewHandlingStrategy` here if it was really treated as a Facelets file.

Let's look back at the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/beginner/faces/index.jsf
```

Huh? It contains 2 (two!) typical `FacesServlet` URL mapping patterns! The `/faces/*` and `*.jsf`. Big chance that it caused some confusion in JSF's internal code if you actually have registered them *both* in your webapp's `web.xml` (like as many poor quality online tutorials and code sampes do). If a physical Facelets file couldn't be found, it namely fallbacks to JSP as default. If the `/faces/*` mapping were matched, then JSF would assume the `/index.jsf` to be the physical file. However, it clearly isn't. It's supposed to be the `/index.xhtml`.

How exactly did you come to that URL with the double mapping? Was the tutorial you're reading really instructing you like that? Shouldn't you rather instead be using

```
http://localhost:8080/beginner/index.jsf
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/beginner/faces/index.xhtml
```

?

Note that the `/faces` is in this specific case supposed to be a virtual URL, not an actual folder in the web content of your project sturcture!

In any case ... Those URL mapping patterns are a leftover of legacy JSF 1.x era. Since JSF 2.0, it's possible to just map the `FacesServlet` on `*.xhtml` directly without messing with virtual URLs.

If you can, get rid of all other `<servlet-mapping>` and `<url-pattern>` so that you end up with ultimately this for the `FacesServlet`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you can open the page by

```
http://localhost:8080/beginner/index.xhtml
```

exactly as its actual path is in the deployment. Straightforward enough.

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)
- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info), to get started with JSF the right way

Comment: Very good as always, +1. One question, does this FacesServlet mapping work for Facelets 1.x running inside JSF 2?

Comment: @EJP: Nope, unfortunately not. It would end up in stack overflow.