# Why the fields in my login page disappear when I redirect after a ViewExpiredException?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, viewexpiredexception

I add the following lines to web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/login/login.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

to redirect to login page when the session expires and it is in fact redirecting but the fields name and password and the button "fazer login" disappear:
[image]
[image]

Heres the relevant code in the  login page:

```
<div class="conteudo">
    <div class="icone-produto"></div>
    <div class="coluna-direita">
        <div class="logo-produto" alt="Wplex-EP"></div>
        <div class="card signin-card">

            <h:panelGrid columns="1">

                <h:dataTable value="#{funcionarioController.lista}"
                    rendered="false"></h:dataTable>
                <h:dataTable value="#{escalaController.lista}" rendered="false"></h:dataTable>
                <h:dataTable value="#{indisponibilidadeController.lista}"
                    rendered="false"></h:dataTable>
                <h:dataTable value="#{programacoesController.programacoes}"
                    rendered="false"></h:dataTable>
                <h:dataTable value="#{funcionarioController.lista}"
                    rendered="false"></h:dataTable>

                <h:inputText class="texto" placeholder="Usuário" 
                    value="#{loginController.login}" />
                <h:inputSecret class="texto" placeholder="Senha" 
                    value="#{loginController.senha}"/>

                <h:commandLink id="fazerLoginId" action="#{loginController.isLoginOk}"
                    styleClass="btn btn-wplex mouseon">
                    Fazer Login
                </h:commandLink>

            </h:panelGrid>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The disappearing elements are actually all JSF components. This part,

```
<location>/login/login.xhtml</location>
```

must match the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet` entry in the very same `web.xml` in order to get it to parse the XHTML and render the JSF components as HTML. Apparently you don't have any one on `*.xhtml`. Perhaps it's `*.jsf` or `/faces/*`. You'd need to alter the `<location>` accordingly to match the `<url-pattern>` of the `FacesServlet`, so that it gets invoked. E.g. in case of `*.jsf`:

```
<location>/login/login.jsf</location>
```

An alternative is to just use an `<url-pattern>` of `*.xhtml`, so that you never need to fiddle and get confused with virtual URLs.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

#### See also:

- [JSF Facelets: Sometimes I see the URL is .jsf and sometimes .xhtml. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why)

Comment: I see, my <url-pattern> is *.jsf so it must be it. Where should I look if wanna go deeper on this subject (what these tags mean, how web.xml and jsf work with each other, etc)?

Comment: Just take a step back and learn basic servlets. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info