# Customize how the url looks in java web application

Tags: java, url, primefaces

Im using:

- NetBeans
- Maven web application
- Java server faces
- Primefaces

To navigate betwen pages im using:

```
            <p:menu>
                <p:submenu label="Menu">
                    <p:menuitem value="example 1 (google)"  outcome="googlePage" />
                    <p:menuitem value="Upload File's" outcome="uploadFiles" />
                    <p:menuitem value="example 3 (go to START)" outcome="index" />
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menu>
```

The  1st url looks like:

```
http://localhost:8080/projectName/
```

and than, when i want to go to other page the url is not looking good:

```
http://localhost:8080/projectName/faces/googlePage.xhtml
```

and the same for index page:

```
http://localhost:8080/projectName/faces/index.xhtml
```

what i need to do to make it more frendly?

Comment: Can you show what is "friendly"? Give some example of what you "desire" and we will try help.

Comment: someting like this: localhost:8080/index || localhost:8080/index/somePage  || i mean without this "faces" and project name. and why when i start  my project the url is short and than when i want back to the start form is longer.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Prettyfaces for that.

> PrettyFaces is an OpenSource URL-rewriting library with enhanced support for JavaServer Faces – JSF 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0 – enabling creation of bookmark-able, pretty URLs. PrettyFaces solves the “RESTful URL” problem elegantly, including features such as: page-load actions, seamless integration with faces navigation, dynamic view-id assignment, managed parameter parsing, and configuration-free compatibility with other web frameworks.

Read more for example [here](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prettyfaces?sort=votes).