# jsf2-javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml except

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, propertynotfoundexception

I am new to JSF.
I have done everything right as far as I know but still getting this exception

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @22,55 value="#{navigator.pages}": Property 'pages' not found on type Navigator
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'pages' not found on type Navigator
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:266)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:243)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:353)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 40 more
```

I have gone through lots of post regarding this exception and they all have mentioned about bean properties and their getters/setters which I have done correctly .

Here is my code:

1) Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
<!--  When you make your own projects, copy and rename sample-file-with-form.xhtml
      or sample-file-no-form.xhtml. Don't copy and rename THIS file, because
      this file has too many extraneous things in it. -->
<h:head>
<title>JSF 2.2: Initial Learning Project</title>
<link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h1 class="title">JSF 2.2: Initial Learning Project</h1>

<div align="center">
<fieldset>
<legend>Selected Results Page</legend>
<h:form>
Please enter the page you want to see.
<br/>
<h:inputText id="pages"  value="#{navigator.pages}" /><br />
<h:commandButton value="Go to Selected Page"
action="#{navigator.choosePage}"/>
</h:form>
</fieldset>
</div>
</h:body></html>
```

2) My bean class -  Navigator.java

```
import javax.faces.bean.*;

@ManagedBean
public class Navigator {

    private String pages;

    public String getPages() {
        return pages;
    }

    public void setPages(String pages) {
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public String choosePage() {
        if(pages == "page1"){
            return "page1";
        } else if(pages == "page2"){
            return "page2";
        } else {
            return "page3";
        }
    }
```

3) web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         version="3.0">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (default). See JSF Specification section 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <!-- If you go to http://host/project/ (with no file name), it will
       try index.jsf first, welcome.jsf next, and so forth.
   -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>welcome.jsf</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

4)faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
  <!--  Empty for now. There are many uses for faces-config.xml, but
        the most common are navigation rules (instead of having
        the return value of the "action" method be the base filename),
        bean declarations (instead of using @ManagedBean), and
        properties files (aka resource bundles).

        If you are not using faces-config.xml, it is perfectly legal
        to omit the file entirely. But, most people prefer to have
        a blank one already in their project for later use.

        From JSF 2 and PrimeFaces tutorial
        at http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/ -->
</faces-config>
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: The reason you get this error might be related to the pages variable not having anything assigned to it. My IDE warns me for this, so I always initialize it (= null e.g.) Try this

Comment: Two things: Your `==` comparission of pages with "page1" and "page2" is wrong, it should be `.equals(..)` and your code works for me, as is, in WildFly 8 (not sure what EL resolver is in there, no intention to check) with java7

Comment: No luck man . Using eclipse Luna with java8 + tomcat 7.

Comment: No luck with what?  The lottery?

Comment: I changed it according to your suggestion but same fate

Comment: The url-pattern for Faces Servlet is *.jsf and the view is index.html. How come that work @Kukeltje?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar  typo... most likely the view is just called .xhtml (and that is then still not related to the url pattern, but the java.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why and since the EL **is** evaluated, the page is loaded correctly. So your answer below is not related (and thus downvoted)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, did'nt know that

Answer (score 0):

try equals for String

```
 public String choosePage()
    {
        if(pages.equals("page1")){
            return "page1";
        } else if(pages.equals("page2")){
            return "page2";
        } else {
            return "page3";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Try with the below changes.

Change filename from index.html to index.xhtml and update the same file name as mentioned below.

`<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>`

*Happy coding!*