# How to set up csrf protection in jsf2.2 web application?

Tags: java, security, jsf, owasp

I have a jsf 2.2 web application without using the spring framework.

I searched on google and **found out that jsf 2.2 provides out of the box csrf protection and you just have to enable it**.

So I did that following this link.
[Jsf2.2 csrf demo](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/JSF-CSRF-Demo/JSF2.2CsrfDemo.html)

And added this in my faces.config.xml file

```
<protected-views>
    <url-pattern>/csrf_protected_page.xhtml</url-pattern>
</protected-views>
```

But how to set up url-pattern for all my .xhtml pages
I have tried:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/faces/*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

But none of these work.

Comment: what does 'none of these work' lead to? WW-III? Intrest rates going up? ;-) Or any errors? And please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969415/should-protected-views-be-used-for-jsf-2-2-csrf-protection first. You might not need this after all

Comment: Affectively btw, you know how to set it up, your title should be _'how to protect many urls in an easy way with <protected-views>'_

Comment: @Kukeltje Do you know the solution on how all .xhtml pages can be included in url-pattern?

Comment: No, did not furter investigate this by using search-engines.

Comment: And the links you provided are not very much helpful in my scenario.

Comment: I never said it would solve it. But it DOES contain info that it is sort of not needed for most (all?) pages so a generic 'catch all' is not very relevant. That is where I stopped searching.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29104597/view-declared-in-protected-views-still-accessible-after-manipulating-csrf-toke