# f:viewParam and f:viewAction not called with *.faces and *.jsf mapping, but only with *.xhtml

Tags: jsf-2, viewparams, servlet-mapping, viewaction

I have a strange behaviour in my webapp. I have bound `*.faces`, `*.jsf` and `*.xhtml` to my Faces Servlet. All my pages are reachable about this mappings, but with `*.faces` and `*.jsf` endings the setter of my `<f:viewParam>` and the method of my `<f:viewAction>` are not called. Do you have any ideas why this could be the case?

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? And just out of curiousity, why exactly three mappings? Why exactly also with JSF 1.x style *.faces and *.jsf mappings? Those offer no real advantages over *.xhtml while the latter has only advantages over the former. Perhaps interesting as background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/jsf-facelets-sometimes-i-see-the-url-is-jsf-and-sometimes-xhtml-why

Comment: It´s jsf 2.2.10. We´re relaunching an application and want to keep old links alive, which are listening to the *.faces mapping. I allready try some other jsf versions. From 2.2.6 to 2.2.11. But problem stays the same.