# JSF request forward

Tags: jsf, filter, request, forward

I have an authentication filter where I check if the session scoped bean is initialized or not.
If it's null I would like to forward to login page.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,FilterChain chain) {
    UserBean ub = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getAttribute("userBean");
    if(ub == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.xhtml").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
 ........
}
```

The problem with this code is that I get the login.xhtml page as xhtml, I mean the tags are not converted to html tags.

As a note: I want to use the `forward` method because I don't want the URL with login.xhtml to be saved in browser history.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3008504/4899193

Comment: It's working only if I use 2 patterns on servlet.
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

Comment: You should use **.jsf** instead of **.xhtml**.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto: why? Depends on the jsf config

Comment: It's working with <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
I used a wrong URL previously

Thank you.