# JSF HTTP Status 404 – Not Found in Hello world program

Tags: jsf, http-status-code-404

I tried to make a hello world program in jsf. I want to run  xhtml file in eclipse (I still haven't used Java), but I can't start it. I get only general error

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found: Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

My other .jsp files run without problem. When I run the xhtml file, this is exact link showing in a browser: http://localhost:8080/JSFProjectHello/faces/hello-world.xhtml There are files of the jsf project:

```
/JSFProjectHello/WebContent/hello-world.xhtml

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<h:head>
    <title>Hello World - Input Form</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{theUserName}" 
                        a:placeholder="What's your name?" />

        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="myresponse" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

.

```
/JSFProjectHello/WebContent/hello-world.xhtml

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Hello World - Response</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    Hello, #{theUserName}

</h:body>
</html>
```

.

```
/JSFProjectHello/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>JSFProjectHello</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>hello-world.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

.
Finally, I should add I use Java8 and as a server Tomcat9. And I've imported this library into the project:

```
/JSFProjectHello/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/javax.faces-2.2.8-sources.jar
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/sometimes-i-see-jsf-url-is-jsf-sometimes-xhtml-and-sometimes-faces-why

Comment: Is `/WebContent/` proper here? I have `web` in my applications.

Comment: Read the link @JasperDeVries posted carefully. The faces folder is superfluous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an error finally. I downloaded incorrect library javax.faces-2.2.8-sources.jar, the correct one should be javax.faces-2.2.8.jar