# JSF with ExtensionlessURLs / Omnifaces

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I´m trying to use ExtensionlessURLs in my JSF app...

I´m using already: https://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs
This works fine, but if I have a URL with a parameter it´s still with:

> mypage.jsf?myparameter=12345

Is there a possibility to exclude here also .jsf, so the URL will be:

> mypage?myparameter=12345

I know also Prettyfaces is available, but here I guess I have to define for each JSF page a mapping? Therefore I was using Omnifaces...

Any idea to help here?

Comment: e.g. like: ```ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
   String id = employee.getId();
   ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/portal/employeeEdit.jsf" + "?id=" + id);```

Comment: Yes, it´s redirected than to /portal/employeeEdit.jsf?id=1234 but I want to have: /portal/employeeEdit?id=1234   (=without "jsf").. without parameter it´s working fine with Omnifaces...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you've an existing JSF application whose `FacesServlet` is mapped to `*.jsf` instead of `*.xhtml` and are trying to enable extensionless URLs through OmniFaces FacesViews using its default "minimal" configuration.

This will indeed not work without making other changes to the existing JSF application.

FacesViews expects that you have already mapped the `FacesServlet` to the URL pattern of `*.xhtml` which is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008395/sometimes-i-see-jsf-url-is-jsf-sometimes-xhtml-and-sometimes-faces-why/3008504) since JSF 2.0. So you need to make the following adjustments:

1. Change `FacesServlet` mapping from `*.jsf` to `*.xhtml` in `web.xml`.
2. Find & replace all occurrences of `.jsf` throughout source code with `.xhtml`. So e.g.

   ```
   ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/portal/employeeEdit.jsf" + "?id=" + id);
   ```

   must become

   ```
   ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/portal/employeeEdit.xhtml" + "?id=" + id);
   ```

   A bit decent IDE can do this in a few clicks (e.g. Eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, *File Search*, find `.jsf` in *Enclosing project* and replace by `.xhtml`).

Alternatively, wait for OmniFaces 2.7.11 or 3.11 or 4.0-M8 to be released. I've today fixed this backwards compatibility issue in these versions as per [issue 623](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/623). With this fix, the existing `*.jsf` URLs will properly be automatically 301-redirected to the extensionless ones.

Note that this problem is not specifically related to URLs with parameters. It would also happen to URLs without parameters.

Comment: thanks BalusC.... I have currently in my web.xml: ```<!-- Map following files to the JSF servlet -->
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>```

Comment: You need to action #2 as well. I've edited the answer to elaborate that a bit more.

Comment: @VonC: Thank you :) I can say the same about your Git-related contributions!