# Servlet Mapping using web.xml

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, java-ee-5

I have a confusion regarding the structure of the web.xml for the servlet mapping, I don't have any problem by executing it but I am trying to figure it how why we have such a pattern in the deployment descriptor.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
         <servlet-path>foo.Servlet</servlet-path>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/enroll</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now as far as my understanding whenever a request is comes for url-pattern "/enroll", servlet container is going to match the servlet-name with the url-pattern and will try to find the corresponding servlet-path and will forward the control to foo.Servlet. so basically there would be two passes one for finding servlet-name and another for servlet-path, my question is if container is designed to work in the following way

```
<web-app>
        <servlet>
             <servlet-name>foo.Servlet</servlet-path>
             <url-pattern>/enroll</url-pattern>
        </servlet>
</web-app>
```

what would be the drawback if we use the following approach. Wouldn't that be more efficient and the response time would be fast.

Comment: Why do you think a different XML schema would affect runtime performance?

Comment: well I was just concern about the number of pass required to fetch the actual value

Comment: Typically, the servlet container just reads the `web.xml` and creates its representation in memory. It's magnitude times faster than reading the `web.xml` each time the request comes.

Comment: [A tutorial to create servlets and map servlets in web.xml](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0L9yTE_zFM0)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It allows servlets to have multiple servlet mappings:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-path>foo.Servlet</servlet-path>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/enroll</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pay</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bill</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It allows filters to be mapped on the particular servlet:

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter1</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Servlet1</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Your proposal would support neither of them. Note that the `web.xml` is read and parsed only once during application's startup, not on every HTTP request as you seem to think.

Since Servlet 3.0, there's the [`@WebServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation which minimizes this boilerplate:

```
@WebServlet("/enroll")
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
```

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)
- [Difference between each instance of servlet and each thread of servlet in servlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183974/difference-each-instance-of-servlet-and-each-thread-of-servlet-in-servlets)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: Thanks BalusC ... but in my approach you can define the multiple servlet like  <web-app>
        <servlet>
             <servlet-name>foo.Servlet</servlet-path>
             <url-pattern>/enroll</url-pattern>                     <servlet-name>foo.Servlet2</servlet-path>
             <url-pattern>/work</url-pattern><servlet-name>foo.Servlet3</servlet-path>
             <url-pattern>/read</url-pattern>
        </servlet>
</web-app>   and the same we can to with the filter mapping

Comment: You're basically creating 3 servlet instances instead of 1. Please read the "see also" links to understand better how servlets work.

Comment: Awesome answer! Well explained! :) Thanks a lot!