# Explanation for servlet and servlet-mapping in web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PerformReg</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.PerformRegistartion</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PerformReg</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PerformReg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

According to me above code is used to map `servlet-class` with its `url-pattern`.
But I have a doubt in my mind that why they (java experts) had done it this way (why have they made the `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` two separate tags).
They could have done something as mentioned below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-class>com.PerformRegistartion</servlet-class>
    <url-pattern>/PerformReg</url-pattern>
</servlet>
```

This may make it more simple. What is the need of `servlet-name` in previous mentioned code?

Please help me to clear my doubt.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question should show some effort of research. Try using google or other answers that can help , before asking a similar question

Comment: @Sajith My question is something different than your suggested link. I want to ask that 'Why we need servlet-name?' In second code block I wrote the code which serve the mapping between servlet-class and url-pattern.

Comment: You question might be answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8198327/468763)

Comment: Using servlet name, You can map single Servlet to multiple url patterns and it allows to map filters with particular Servlet. See here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198312/servlet-mapping-using-web-xml/8198327#8198327

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml you use servlet-name as unique reference to your servlet.
This name indentifies the servlet and can be used with filters and so on.
It isn't just a matter of mapping your servlet to a specific URL.

You can look at it as an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Name always will be the unique identification for classes. Here serlvelt-class may come two times, but whatever we are calling servlet should be unique. That will identified by the servlet name. If you see in struts1 or struts2 or spring will have names offcourse in spring id. but identification should be mandatory whether it is in name or ID.

In servlet also servlet class is triggered by servlet name only not by servlet class.because one class will perform amny different actions. Each action should be identify by the name.

Comment: In the future, do not include unrelated links to your site in your posts. Doing so will get your posts and account marked as Spam. I am removing the link from this post for you.

Answer (score 0):

In `web.xml`, we first configure the servlet using the `< servlet >` element providing a unique name i.e in `< servlet-name >` tag and writes the class name of the servlet in `< servlet-class >` tag.

Second, we map this servlet to a URL or URL pattern using `< servlet-mapping >` element.
`< servlet-name >` element is used to specify the name of the servlet, which should be called for an incoming URL matching the pattern specified as the value of the `< url-pattern >` element.