# Difference between <servlet-path> and <servlet-class> tag?

Tags: servlets

Is there any difference between servlet-path and servlet-class tags when you define a servlet mapping under web.xml?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
    <servlet-path>box.RegisterServlet</servlet-path>
</servlet>
```

Say if were to change servlet-path to servlet-class would it make any difference?
If not,why are there 2 separate tags for doing the same thing?
Thanks!

Comment: Biggest difference is that one exists, one doesn't.

Comment: If servlet-path does not exist, why does the accepted answer for ["Servlet Mapping using web.xml"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8198327/565288) use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such attribute as `<servlet-path/>` in Servlet Spec. Only `<servlet-class/>` is allowed. Does it even work for you?

## See also

- [`web-app_2_5.xsd`](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd)
- [`web-app_3_0.xsd`](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd)

Comment: @Ash Seems painful, but okay. I'd rather beat Comcast.

Comment: I have seen this kind of declaration while browsing on the internet for a similar question.

Comment: Must have mistaken it with something else.My bad.