# jsp : delete file when click on html link

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to delete files after a click on an HTML link in a `jsp` page.

The following is my `jsp` code:

```
<%
File f=new File("c:\\Folder\\1.jpg");
f.delete();
%>
```

What `href` should I use in the HTML code?

```
<a href......>Delete me </a>
```

Comment: For important security reasons you cannot delete a file on somebody's computer when they click a buton on a web page.

Comment: Is your goal to delete a file that exists on the server?  If so, see the answer by @shreyanshjogi.  You can do what he suggests or make a request to a servlet (which would be better).  To make a request to a Servlet, you need to configure your container to map URL patterns to your servlet.  Here's [a question about servlet mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8198312/778118).  You'll have to google about how to set up servlet mapping on whatever container you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use j query to delete without refreshing 
 Here is the code lets have a try

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $( "#deletefilesAnchor" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete Files?')) {
        // Save it!
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "action.jsp",
                success: function(msg){
                    alert(msg)
                },
             });
        } else {
        // Do nothing!
        }
   }); 
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="deletefilesAnchor" href="#">Delete files</a>
</body>
</html>
```

action.jsp

```
<%
File f=new File("c:\\Folder\\1.jpg");
if(f.delete())
out.println("Sucessfully deleted file");
else
out.println("Error in deleting file");
%>
```

Answer (score 5):

`Html` plays on client side and `Java(Jsp)` plays on server side.You need  to make a `server request` for that.

And one more point

```
File f=new File("c:\\Folder\\1.jpg");
```

After you made the `request` the above line tries to remove the file from the `server` not from the user machine(who clicked the link).

You might misunderstand that `jsp` and `html` existed on same document. Yes but `JSP` part compiles on server side itself and JSP output resolves as html and is sent to the `client`.

Note:Html and Javascript cannot have access to files on the machine due to security reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(request.getParameter("btnSubmit")!=null) //btnSubmit is the name of your button, not id of that button.
{
File f=new File("c:\\Folder\\1.jpg");
f.delete();
}

<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="delete"/>
```

This you you can achieve

Comment: Note that this will only delete files that exist on the server (i.e. the computer that hosts the website).  It will have no effect on a person who is using a web browser on their personal computer.

Comment: they can check on the file whether file exist or not?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Could you please clarify?  Code can be written that does just about anything to files on the server.  **But**, you cannot manipulate files on somebody's computer using code that runs in a browser (unless you're using ActiveX or a Java applet or some kind of plugin).

Comment: that is java code so obeviously you are manipulation from the hosted once and if i run from my machine code is available at hosted location not in my pc and even file is also at hosted location. so will it be create any problem to delete?

Comment: There is no reason you can't delete a file on the server.  Maybe that's what the OP actually wants.  If so, this answer is correct.  Hopefully the OP will clarify what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't do that like this way.**

servlet/jsp is run on the server side, but the html link is run on the client side(the browser). If you see the source code of the page(click the right button of the mouse over the browser page), then you can see the jsp code is not exist.

If you want to do that, your should link to another page(like b.jsp), then in the jsp, use the the code above to delete the file.