# Calling servlet from a JSP page's form action

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to pass a value input to a textbox in a JSP page to a servlet that will store the value as a variable. But when I click the submit button the servlet isn't found. I get an error stating `the requested resource is not available`

Servlet Class:

```
    //parse input from hello.jsp input box 
    //and assign to fibNum variable
    
    
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        
        
    }
    

}
```

I've looked at some questions like this: [<form action="/sampleServlet" giving me exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683877/form-action-sampleservlet-giving-me-exception) but changing the path didn't change the outcome.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem calling of a servlet? Or is there a step I'm missing in linking up the servlet?

[image: res]

[image: package]

Also this is the structure of my project tree:

Comment: @Reimeus just updated the question to include the ``wem.xml`. Could this issue be because there has to be a reference to the servlet in this file?

Comment: can you post your servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create servlet mapping in your [web.xml](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198312/servlet-mapping-using-web-xml) as well.
So in your web.xml define;

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class><package name>.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Then create mappings (url patterns) for the servlet.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/say_hello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now in your JSP refernce the servlet like

```
 <form action="say_hello" method="get">            
   <b>Fibonacci Sequence Length </b>  <br>
   <input type="text" name="fibNum"size="20px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px" >
   <input type="submit" value="submit" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px" > <br>  
   Value [1-100]<br>
 </form>
```

Comment: I tired the above but it seems there is a problem with on one of  the tags at the line:  `<servlet-class><package ie.gmit>.HelloServlet</servlet-class>`. The error I'm geting is `Attribute name "name" associated with an element type "package" must be followed by the ' = ' character.`

Comment: I also had to change the form action to `post` to match the servlet.

Comment: The above solution worked, just had to correct the mappings as pointed out, How could I pass an integer array to the jsp page instead of just an integer value? I was thinking something like this:`resp.sendRedirect(("result.jsp?fibSeq=" + fibSeq));` but then I get the eeror: `fibSeq cannot be resolved to a variable` I'm guessing there is a different method involved for passing an array? The integer array is declared like `int[] fibSequence`

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass the servlet name same as your url_pattern(web.xml) to action tag of form.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do mapping in web.xml with url pattern - HelloServlet.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your code you just missed out some servlet declaration in *web.xml* file

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>...</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>...</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>...</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>...</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Final Solution:**
Tomcat 10 has problem please remove. download tomcat 9 from
https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi.

I tried in Eclipse and Intellij with Tomcat 9 it works but the same code with Tomcat 10 has problem.