# How to update a database using SQL in jsp

Tags: sql, jsp

I have a database and a table called `itemDetail` it contains 2 fields : `itemName` and `quantity`

Using `jsp` how do I deduct/update from the database depend on the number I input?

Example

Initial quantity = 100
Html form quantity  = 1
The SQL statement should update the database so 
Quantity - html form quantity
New quantity  in database = 99

Please help me.

Thanks.

Sample of my coding

```
<%

String iName = request.getParameter("itemName");
String Qty = request.getParameter("quantity");
String price = request.getParameter("price"); 

//out.print("itemName");
//out.print("quantity");
//out.print("price");
%>

<%-- <jsp:setProperty name="MrBeanA" property="itemName" /> 
<jsp:setProperty name="MrBeanA" property="Quantity" /> --%>

<%@ page import = "java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Statement"%>

<%
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");

Statement s = con.createStatement();
int yrwish = s.executeUpdate( "insert into Inventory (itemName, Qty, Price) values ('" + iName + "','" + Qty + "','" + price + "')");

s.close();
con.close();
%>

<%
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");

Statement delete = con.createStatement();
int yrwish2 = delete.executeUpdate("UPDATE itemDetail SET quantity =("+quantity-Qty+")WHERE itemName=+iName");

delete.close();
con1.close();

%>
```

Error
An error occurred at line: 44 in the jsp file: /myjsp/Confirm.jsp
Generated servlet error:
quantity cannot be resolved

which is

```
<%
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Project");

Statement delete = con.createStatement();
int yrwish2 = delete.executeUpdate("UPDATE itemDetail SET quantity =("+quantity-Qty+")WHERE itemName=+iName");

delete.close();
con1.close();

%>
```

Comment: English+Question is not clear. Please re-write the sentences in a simple way. Even the Subject of the question is too dark!

Comment: Errors:
Spelling of Statement at line 43, s object is closed and now used at line 44, instead use delete object to execute query. And use this 
int yrwish2 = delete.executeUpdate("UPDATE itemDetail SET quantity = ("+quantity - Qty+") WHERE itemName="+iName);  

Hope it helps !

Comment: try this int yrwish2 = delete.executeUpdate("UPDATE itemDetail SET quantity = (quantity - "+Qty+") WHERE itemName="+iName);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to do this on same page use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

else use form to get input and run Servlet on submit where you can update the database [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369840/calling-servlet-from-a-jsp-pages-form-action?rq=1)

[Demo of HTML Form](http://jsfiddle.net/9e1enfj6/)

On form Submission , the Servlet will run which is in 'action' attribute

Code for Servlet : Not tested

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                            throws ServletException, IOException {
  String name = req.getParameter("itemName");
  int val = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("itemq").trim());

  Connection con = null;
  try {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" +
                               "user=minty&password=greatsqldb");
```

Edited:

```
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("select quantity from itemDetail where itemName = "+iName); 
   rs1.next();
   int quantity = rs1.getInt("quantity"); //column label in database
   stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE itemDetail SET quantity = "+(quantity - val)+" where itemName = "+name);

   con.commit();   
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
 }
 finally {
    if (con != null)
       con.close();
 }
}
}
```

Edited: Errors for reference to OP :

- Spelling of Statement at line 43
- s object is closed and now used at line 44, instead use delete object to execute query.
- And use this `int yrwish2 = delete.executeUpdate("UPDATE itemDetail SET quantity = (quantity - "+Qty+") WHERE itemName="+iName);`

Hope it helps !

Comment: I have now given a html form to take itemName and quantity and servlet for updating the quantity from database.

Comment: I add some of my coding.. please assist.