# error 404 not found - servlet from JSP

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

I have a simple random number generator built. I was trying to use a servlet with a form. The first page pulls up just fine. After hitting the button to get the random numbers I get 'HTTP Status 404 - Not_Found' The requested resource is not available.

I have looked for anything I might have mistyped, or missing any ':' etc. 
It all looks good to me so I was hoping that someone could put a different set of eyes on it and maybe tell me what a noob I am.

Here is my JSP file:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Random Numbers Page</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white">
<H1>Random Numbers Page</h1>
<P>This will display 20 random numbers </P>
<FORM METHOD=POST         ACTION="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/randomNumberServlet">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Get Numbers Here">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And here is my servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class randomNumberServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected final int DEFAULT_NUMBER = 20;

 /** Called when the form is filled in by the user.
 * @param req
 * @param resp
 * @throws java.io.IOException */
 @Override
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
 throws IOException {
resp.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter( );

// HTML setup stuff.
out.println("<HTML>");
out.println("<HEAD>");
out.println("<BODY BGCOLOR=\"white\">");

// HTML for this page
out.println("<TITLE>Random Numbers</TITLE>");
out.println("<P>Here are the 20  random numbers,");

// Now actually generate some random numbers.
// Now actually generate some random numbers.
Random r = new Random(100);
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
  out.print("<LI>");
  out.println(r.nextInt());  

out.println("</OL>");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your web.xml. Also is the servlet in a package or default package. If the servlet is in default package move it to a package name and try

Comment: I am not sure how to get that. I will google it and learn though. In the end after working on this for more than 20 hours in two days I figured it out. I made this more complicated then it really was.

Comment: Ended up putting the regular java code inside the JSP file. The only thing I had done wrong was trying to put it in the '_body'. I had to put it outside of any area designated already (body, head, title etc).

Comment: I still want to figure this out using the above method so I will get the web.xml for you. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the url mapping /randomNumberServlet does not point to the randomNumberServlet servlet.
You have 2 options:

1. In your web xml [define your servlet and a URL mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198312/servlet-mapping-using-web-xml)
2. Or, If your servlet container is Servlet 3.0 Specification complaint, you can use [Servlet Annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations).

Here's a Servlet Annotation example:

```
@WebServlet(name="randomNumberServlet", urlPatterns={"/randomNumberServlet"}) 
public class randomNumberServlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```