# resource not found error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I have created a program in eclipse using servlet only where it asks about log in details.if paasword is correct the user name and message is displayed. however when I write user name and password the eclipse displays resource not found. can someone please tell me what the problem is?

index.html

```
<form action="go" method="get">
Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/><br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="userPass"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="login"/>

</form>
```

Simple.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


public class Simple extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String p=request.getParameter("userPass");
        if(p.equals("servlet")){
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
        else{
            out.print("Sorry username or password error!");
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

WelcomeServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String n=request.getParameter("userName");
        out.print("Welcome "+n);
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Simple</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Simple</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Simple</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/go</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: i have added it. can you please help me coz i have been stuck with this problem

Comment: How does your web.xml file looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Server is not able to map your request to a servlet.In code snippet

```
<form action="go" method="get">
```

Here on click of submit button,you are calling servlet "go" which is not available in your application rather i would say not mapped to any servlet you specified here.

Either you can use web.xml for servlet mapping or you can use annotations for that purpose.

> Servlets should be registered with servlet container. For that, you
>   should add entries in web deployment descriptor web.xml. It is located
>   in WEB-INF directory of the web application.

If you want to use annotations,You can use @WebServlet to map your servlet.

### See Also

- [Servlet Mapping Using web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198312/servlet-mapping-using-web-xml)
- [Servlet 3.0 Annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations)

Comment: thanks a lot..it helped me. the program was executed but when i gave correct password it displayed server at 123 (123 is my project name).what i should do to display a message when i type correct password???

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your effort in start learning from the mere basics of `Servlets`. Here are few corrections/observations:

1. You receive resource not found on accessing the application is because of the `welcome-file` configuration. You have it as `login.html` and the your login page is `index.html`. Add an entry `index.html` to `web.xml` or rename `index.html` to `login.html`
2. When any user name is entered with password `servlet`, it shows the welcome message and that is great! But if the password does not match it tries to find `login.html` and it fails.