# How the servlets are shared among every request

Tags: java, servlets

How the servlets are shared among every request?  I understand that each httprequest are allocated to different thread.  How about concurrent request?

Comment: there is only one instance of a servlet in a container and it is used to serve all requests. Requests are concurrently handled, and servlets are not thread safe by default (you can put synchronized blocks/ methods if you like). is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: What is the role of servlet pooling? Is that the same as EJB session pooling?

Comment: sorry but I don't know if there's anything called servlet pooling... where did you read about it? AFAIK, there's nothing to pool (just one instance per container)...

Comment: Ok got it thanks.  I got confused with this http://oreilly.com/catalog/jservlet/chapter/ch03.html#25306

Comment: oh, thanks for the link. I would personally avoid SingleThreadModel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Towards understanding servlets and multi-threading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446989/towards-understanding-servlets-and-multi-threading)

Answer (score 1):

When you create your servlet you decide whether you will make it single threaded or multi-threaded. You can mark your servlet as single-threaded by implementing the interface

```
javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel
```

[See this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch03_04.htm)

A single threaded servlet can serve only one request at a time, and that's usually not what we want. So typically we allow our servlets to be multi-threaded and implement accordingly. Code on the assumption that many threads, each of which corresponds to one user's request, may be in our servlet at the same time. This is not hard to do - avoid using instance variables that can be changed by any one request thread and remember that any synchronized code will become a point of contention.

Comment: it may be worth noting that SingleThreadModel is actually [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html)

Answer (score 0):

When a Servlet is requested for the first time or when the webapp starts up, the servlet container will create an instance of it and keep it in memory during webapp's lifetime. The same instance will be reused for every incoming request whose URL matches the servlet's URL pattern.

A separate thread is created to handle each HttpServlet Request.

See [Servlet Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for details.The info has links to great resources that would give you a better understanding of servlets.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that each httprequest are allocat[ed] to different thread.

Correct.

> How about concurrent request?

They are allocated to different threads.

Comment: So, while processing request from the first thread the second thread has to wait?

Comment: @Thurein No, they are allocated to different threads, and threads are concurrent. There's no 'so' about it.