# java servlet questions:One singleton class for all requests or create instances for each request?

Tags: http, servlets

I have now created a java servlet program,the servlet class which extends HttpServlet is named **com.servlet.Main**. As we all know , every servlet class  has two functions: doGet() and doPost(),one for http get request and the other for http post request. My question is,JVM will **create a new com.servlet.Main instance for each coming request** or **just maintain a singleton instance for all requests**?

Answer (score 0):

A Servlet container will only ever create one instance of your `Servlet` implementation for each declaration in the deployment descriptor. This is not a true singleton, only effectively a singleton relative to the `ServletContext`. Nothing prevents you from creating more instances.

Note, that the entry point of all `Servlet` applications is the `Servlet#service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse)` method. `HttpServlet`, an sub type of `Servlet`, implements this method to delegate to a number of methods which custom implementations should override. These are `doGet`, `doPost`, `doPut`, `doDelete`, `doHead`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The servletcontainer reuses the **same servlet instance for every request**.
See this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183974/difference-between-each-instance-of-servlet-and-each-thread-of-servlet-in-servle)