# Init() or constructor which gets called first in a Java Servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I was just curious which could get called first internally.

I am very much aware that we are not supposed to have constructors in Servlets & it's not good & it spoils the use of Init(),etc. But we DO can have constructors in servelts.

Just any idea? I guess Init() is called by the container itself when placing the servlet in the servlet pool, yet what about a constructor.

Comment: You can find your answer here: [Difference between each instance of servlet and each thread of servlet in servlets?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2183974/1065197)

Comment: Note: I'm not marking your question as a duplicate because it is not a duplicate of that question. But part of the accepted answer solves your problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thank you :) it clearly explains the micro steps of servlet initiation. But I'm afraid it ain't got anything on constructor.

Comment: Covered in this line: `Class.forName(servletClass).newInstance()`. This will invoke the constructor of your servlet.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is called first or else there would be no object to call `init()` on. And yes, the `init()` method is indeed called by the container. The container might decide to re-init a servlet (could possibly prune some of its related object graphs when no activity and re-init it when needed to free memory). If you put any initialization type code in the constructor, it won't get recalled.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafi.html

Comment: You should add that as a general rule, you create a new instance of an object you have to create it using a class constructor through the `new` keyword. Only then, you can call the methods of the object, and `init` is simply a method.