# Why new servlet constructor was not called?

Tags: java, servlets, constructor

Why the web container  always calling the default servlet constructor only ?

and why if default constructor is not present, the container is throwing  exceptions. ?

How to use my custom servlet constructor ? If it is possible.

Comment: This is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2183974/1065197

Comment: I also recommend you to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza isn't the case of marking the question dup?

Comment: If you register your Servlets through code, you can use any constructor you'd like.

Comment: @Leo IMO it's not a direct dup.

Comment: Thanks @LuiggiMendoza .. those answers helped.